# Xcode error presenting UIAlertController the first time on iPads with iOS9

Tags: ios, ipad, ios9, uialertcontroller

Presenting a UIAlertController on any iPad running iOS9 displays the following error in Xcode 7 the ***first*** time the alert is displayed:

```
<CATransformLayer: 0x12cd8a4b0> - changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect
```

The code I am using is stupid simple:

```
- (IBAction)showAlert:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                                   message:@"Message"
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                              style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                            handler:nil]];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This only happens the ***first*** time the alert is presented on iPads running iOS9. Subsequent presentations of the alert do not have errors. iPhones and iOS8 devices are fine.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a known Apple bug?

Answer (score 0):

you can call alert first time when load view controller,in **(void)viewWillAppear** OR *create a alert class* like this:

```
-(void)alert{

UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"                                                                  message:@"Message"                                                         preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"                                            style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil]];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

then use that **after delay**: 
{

```
[self performSelector:@selector(alert) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

}

I hope helpful